# detection of pattern from unstructured data using fuzzy logic

Tags: fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to extract a pattern and trim  data from an unstructured data. I'm using Regx for this . I'm wondering if i can use fuzzy logic to do the same.I'm an amateur when it comes to fuzzy Logic . Should invest my time in it.

ps: my data to be extracted contains bot numbers and words.

Comment: Look into LSH and fuzzy hash, see https://github.com/amirouche/fuzzyhash